# How can I assign two types to a specific key in mongoose schema?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

```js
const pendingMenuSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   
  category: {
    type: [String, mongoose.Schema.ObjectId], // contains existing category id or new category string.
  }
})
```

I want to save either a *ObjectId* or a *string* to the **category** value depending on my use case.
Is it possible to assign two types to a key in mongoose Schema?

If it is possible then how can I implement it in my given schema.
Thanking in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For assigning multiple types we can use the `Mixed` type of `Mongoose`.

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const pendingMenuSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  category: {
    // type: {}, 
    // OR
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed,
  },
});
```

For further reference : [Mongoose Documentation - Schema Types : Mixed](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#mixed)